# ComboBox открывается не на текущем элементе, а в конце списка

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется `ComboBox` со списком шрифтов, первый раз он открывается на выбранном элементе, но после скролла вниз, он открывается в конце списка. При скролле вверх, такого поведения замечено не было. У параметра `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` установлено значение `true`. Как каждый раз открывать DropDown лист на выбранном элементе?

Разметка:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FontComboBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          xmlns:ComponentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
          ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource FontTemplate}"          
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          SelectionChanged="FontComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myFonts" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <ComponentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Source" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
        <Style x:Key="FontStyle">
            <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="{Binding Source}" />
            <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="14" />
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FontTemplate">
            <StackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FontStyle}" ToolTip="{Binding Source}"
                           Text="{Binding Source}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource myFonts}" />
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="FontComboBox_RequestBringIntoView" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Код:

```
private void FontComboBox_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Раз не работает штатно - пишите код для скрола до текущего элемента

Comment: Ага, штатное поведение как раз ломает ваш обработчик `RequestBringIntoView`, поясните, для чего он вам?

Comment: @АндрейNOP [Убирает прокрутку списка указателем мыши](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567219/disable-scrolling-for-mouse-over-in-combobox-wpf)

Comment: Непонятен смысл борьбы с этим поведением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчик `RequestBringIntoView` добавил следующее условие:

```
private void FontComboBox_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (((ComboBoxItem)e.TargetObject).Content == FontComboBox.SelectedItem)
    {
        return;
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Да, судя по исходникам более нормального способа сделать это нету.